How to fix error message "undefined symbol" when launching moveit setup asisstant?
While trying to open the moveit_setup_assistant with the command:
ros2 launch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch.py

I get the error:
/root/ws_moveit/install/moveit_setup_assistant/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: 
symbol lookup error: /root/ws_moveit/install/moveit_setup_assistant/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: 
undefined symbol: _ZN6rclcpp6Logger9get_childERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

What does this error mean?
How do I solve this?
Ros2 installation is Humble
ws_moveit is installed via packages from a remote repository.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL
https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started.html
https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/index.html
I have tried to get some packages for the setup assistent with:
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-moveit-setup-assistant

However this did not fix the problem.
Thanks in advance

you have to put the ``` on a separate line before and after  the message text
